# Match id with class to show correct popup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, svg

I am building a stadium seating chart with wordpress and woocommerce.  I have a popup that shows when you click on a seat on the map.  What I need is for the popup to match the correct seat on the map, so if I click on seat 613 then the popup for 613 shows up.

The popup shows information about the woocommerce product from the database, I already have this working.

Here is the code I have for this

An example of two sections within the SVG map that contain the id's I want to match.

```
<g id="Skye_Terrace" class="available">
    <g id="613" class="section">
      <polygon points=" 82.2 453.2 153.4 426.4 216.5 481.4 146.6 506.9 " class="a"></polygon>
      <text transform="matrix(0.99915 -0.04114 0.04114 0.99915 128.9282227 474.7163086)" class="myriad" font-size="28.1989803">613</text>
    </g>
    <g id="614" class="section">
      <polygon points=" 232.6 395.5 291.7 450.5 216.5 481.4 153.4 426.4 " class="a"></polygon>
    </g>
</g>
```

An example of a popup that should show up on click with the correct woocommerce product information for the matching map section or id

```
<!-- Popup for ticket information -->
        <div class="popup myriadGlobal <?php echo $product->get_attribute( 'section' ); ?>" id="<?php echo $product->get_attribute( 'section' ); ?>">
          <figure>
            <img src="<?php echo plugins_url('images/sample.jpg', __FILE__); ?>" alt=""><img src="<?php echo plugins_url('images/sample.jpg', __FILE__); ?>" alt="">
          </figure>
          <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="col_two">
                <section>
                  <header>
                    <h2>Section <?php echo $product->get_attribute( 'section' ); ?></h2>
                    <h3 id="row">Row
                        <select name="row" id="selectRow">
                            <?php foreach ( $rows as $row) { echo "<option>" . $row->name . "</option>"; } ?>
                        </select>
                    </h3>
                  </header>
              </section>
```

The jQuery I created to try to match the id's until I realized that's not valid so now I need to match the classes.  get_attribute("section") will be the same as an id on the map, for example 613 and 614.

I've updated the code which seems to get the first popup but that's it.  By using next it's targeting only one in the html output.  How do I target all and find the one that matches the svg map id?

```
var position = $('g.available g').offset();
var popup = $('.popup');

popup.each(function(index){

  var id = this.id;
  var className = $('.popup > div').attr('class');
  var $match = $('g.available g[id^="'+id+'"]');

  $match.click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
      if($match.length && className.length){
        $(this).parent().parent().next().next().slideToggle('fast').css(position);
      }
    });
});
```

I've also tried

```
$("g,rect,path,line,circle").click(function() { 
        var classname = $(this).attr("id"); 
        $(".popup").hide(); 
        $("."+classname).show(); 
    });
```

I've even tried to follow this post: [Match incremented class with incremented ids from different loops [jQuery / Wordpress]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28528526/match-incremented-class-with-incremented-ids-from-different-loops-jquery-word?rq=1)

Hopefully this is enough information.  I've been unsuccessful in achieving this for some reason... coders block? lol

EXAMPLE

I'm missing the part where I say

```
if .614 == #614 {
       display the_content()
    }
```

This code comes out as true so I'm not sure why it's not showing the right popup.

```
$('g.available g').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
          var id = $(this).attr('id');
          var className = $('.popup').hasClass(id);
         alert(className);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the polygon g id when click on polygon and create popup div with that id to show.

For example your g id is: 613, create popup div with that id associate with any name like

```
div id="popup_div_613" class="popup">

content area

/ div>
```

Than when click on polygon you can get his parent g attribute id and show popup accordingly.

$("g,rect,path,line,circle").click(function() {

var div_id=jQuery(this).parent().attr("id");

$(".popup").hide();

$("#popup_div_"+div_id).show();

});

Hope this work for you.

Or if this is not work, please share the demo where you are facing this issue, so we can review and understand the process and find a solution.

Comment: that didn't work :( - check out the files here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9tx-iOO3kZneVlZa1Z0Vndxbnc/view?usp=sharing

a demo is here - https://www.derbydeals.com/dummy-chart-page/

Comment: I'm trying to build on this because it seems to be a good foundation

$('g.available g').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var className = $('.popup').hasClass(id);
   alert( "ID is:" + id + className);
  });